# Symfony 3 - You have requested a non-existent service is driving me crazy

Tags: php, symfony

So, this is not the first time I am creating the service but I just can't resolve the error

> You have requested a non-existent service "global_settings".

Steps I took to ensure service is properly setup:

My `AppBundleExtension.php`

```php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('settings.xml');
    }
}
```

My `settings.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container
        xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="global_settings" class="AppBundle\Services\GlobalSettings">
            <call method="setEntityManager">
                <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" />
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

My `GlobalSettings` service

```php
namespace AppBundle\Services;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    class GlobalSettings
    {

        /**
         * @var EntityManager
         */
        protected $em;
        /**
         * @var EntityRepository
         */
        protected $repo;

        public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) {
            $this->em = $em;
            $this->repo = null;
        }

        /**
         * @return array with name => value
         */
        public function all() {
            return $this->$this->getRepo()->findAll();
        }


        /**
         * @param string $name Name of the setting.
         * @return string|null Value of the setting.
         * @throws \RuntimeException If the setting is not defined.
         */
        public function get($name) {
            $setting = $this->$this->getRepo()->findOneBy(array(
                'name' => $name,
            ));
            if ($setting === null) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException($name);
            }
            return $setting->getValue();
        }
        /**
         * @param string $name Name of the setting to update.
         * @param string|null $value New value for the setting.
         * @throws \RuntimeException If the setting is not defined.
         */
        public function set($name, $value) {
            $setting = $this->$this->getRepo()->findOneBy(array(
                'name' => $name,
            ));
            if ($setting === null) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException($name);
            }
            $setting->setValue($value);
            $this->em->flush($setting);
        }
        /**
         * @return EntityRepository
         */
        protected function getRepo() {
            if ($this->repo === null) {
                $this->repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Settings');
            }
            return $this->repo;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $name Name of the setting.
         * @return \RuntimeException
         */
        protected function createNotFoundException($name) {
            return new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Setting "%s" couldn\'t be found.', $name));
        }


    }
```

Then inside my controller I trying to access the service using the following code

```php
$data = $this->get('global_settings')->get('paypal_email');
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be really appreciate as I am out of idea.

Comment: You can use `php app/console debug:container` to list available services. Does your service is listed?

Comment: @A.L yes I tried that and I do not see my service listed there, thats what I am having trouble with that i have everything that i normally do to create the service and yet my service is not working....

Comment: If you add `throw new \Exception('services loaded');` after `$loader->load('settings.xml');`, do you have an exception? If there is no exception, it means that `AppBundleExtension` is not loaded.

Comment: @A.L yes i tried that and i know `AppBundleExtension ` is not loading, what do i need to do to load it? what am i missing?

Comment: Does the name of `AppBundleExtension` match the name of the bundle?

Comment: @A.L Yes, my bundle name is `AppBundle` and the Extension file name is `AppBundleExtension`

Comment: I am using the namespace `namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wrote:

> Steps I took to ensure service is properly setup
>
> My `AppBundleExtension.php`

And:

> I know `AppBundleExtension` is not loading, what do I need to do to load it? What am I missing?

So it was clear that the `AppBundleExtension` class was not loaded.

According to the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class) you should remove the `Bundle` in the file name and class name:

> The name is equal to the bundle name with the `Bundle` suffix replaced by `Extension` (e.g. the Extension class of the AppBundle would be called `AppExtension` and the one for AcmeHelloBundle would be called `AcmeHelloExtension`).

Comment: @Baig I didn't see it immediately neither. It's not obvious that `Bundle` must be removed.

Answer (score 21):

The reason why I kept getting this error was that my default setting for services was `public: false`

So to fix that I needed to set the `public` property to `true` for my service

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    my_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\MyService
        public: true
```

Comment: public: true is compulsory in new version of symfony in services.yml :(

Answer (score 1):

You can update your *config.yml* file:

```yaml
imports: 
      - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```